# angular2+ ngModel can not binding an expression?

Tags: angular

```
<input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="{{_current + 1}}">
```

as the code, I want to banding an expression to ngModel, but report error, why?
and how can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean to say "***binding***"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ngModelChange`:

```
@Component(
 selector: 'my-component',
 templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
)
export class MyComponent{
 _current: number;

 onChange(){
   this._current= this._current+ 1;
 }
}
```

**my-component.component.html**

```
<input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="_current" (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not bind with model using interpolation, you should do it like(without `{{}}`):

```
<input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="_current">
```